# Integrate ack to VIM74 on window7 64bit

Tags: vim, ack

I'm using ack.vim on windows 7 64bit with VIM74(32bit), but i can't get my search results in quickfix windows

This is how my SHELL window display below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (ack.pl -H --nocolor --nogroup --column Flash_Locked ^>C:\Users\edward\AppData\Local\Temp\VIeC84A.tmp 2^>^&1)
```

Anyone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because it's trying to directly invoke `ack.pl`, which only works when you tell Windows to associate the `.pl` file extension with the Perl interpreter.

It's more robust to explicitly specify the Perl interpreter, though: The call should look like: `... cmd.exe /c (perl ack.pl ...` (assuming `perl` is available through `PATH`).